# Convert Date dynamically but time static in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, valueconverter

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Date, 6), ' ', '/') AS Date 
FROM
    TableFiles
```

The statement above converts only date without time which is

```
04-Apr-17
```

But I want the same date format with time in the format below statically

```
12:00:00 AM



SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Date, 6), ' ', '-') + ' ' + 
       LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), Date, 22), 11)) 
FROM
    tblFiles
```

This code returns a dynamic datetime

```
4-Apr-17 7:44:43 AM
```

But I want the time to convert statically to the value `12:00:00 AM`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Date, 6), ' ', '/') + ' 12:00:00 AM' AS Date 
FROM
    TableFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

just an idea: select convert(**date**, yourvalue ) + 0.5) .... should use only date part and add an half day?